# OCaml TCP server only listening locally

Tags: server, ocaml, port

I am building a simple server in OCaml and it only seems to be listening locally. I have forwarded the port in my router and tried turning off firewalls, but it still isn't working.

When I run the server on port `8886` and then run the `netstat` command I get that the service is listening on `127.0.0.1:8886`. How do I get it to listen on all addresses instead of just to localhost?

The code for the server uses the Janestreet Async module and looks like this:

```
Tcp.Server.create 
  ~on_handler_error:`Raise
  (Tcp.Where_to_listen.of_port 8886) 
  (fun _addr r w -> perform_tasks w r)
```

From what I understand in the [documentation](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/latest/doc/async_unix/Async_unix/Tcp/index.html), the `of_port` function should listen on all addresses.

Comment: For the sake of it, try address 0.0.0.0

Comment: Your read of documentation is correct, `Where_to_listen.of_port` binds to `0.0.0.0`, so it should listen on all addresses. Make sure that your problem assessment is correct, i.e., that you're looking at the right server on the right machine. Also, check if your machine has any non-localhost interfaces, it could be that you have only the loopback interface. If it doesn't help, then try to create a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: also check if your firewall is not dropping the packets…